# Bug with audio reCaptcha in safari

Tags: zend-framework, audio, safari, recaptcha

Can other Safari users please test http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html for me, to see if the audio reCaptcha plays properly? On my machine, I can only hear the audio if I click the `Download sound as MP3` link. I also don't get the spoken introduction at all. It works OK in  Firefox and Chrome.

I was alerted to this bug on my own development site, using the Zend Service for ReCaptcha. However, if it's broken on the official site, then I guess it's not a Zend bug. There don't seem to be any JavaScript errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, forget that.

It was my Flash blocker in Safari which prevented the sound from playing. Didn't realise the audio reCaptcha used Flash.